# Как скрыть и показать CollectionReusableView при скролле Colectionview?

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть `Collectionview` в котором есть список уроков
Перед этим списком я добавил хэдер `CollectionReusableView`
Мне нужно чтобы когда форма загружается хэдер был невидим, а когда скролите вниз то он появляется.
Когда у меня был `tableview` этих проблем не возникало
Делал вот так

```
   var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

// this delegate is called when the scrollView (i.e your UITableView) will start scrolling
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}

// while scrolling this delegate is being called so you may now check which direction your scrollView is being scrolled to
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y ) {

        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    } else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y + 30) {

        tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView

        }

}
```

Но у `collectionview` такое не прокатит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите мне
Заранее благодарен

Comment: Вы уверены что вам необходим header? Может просто использовать обычное UIView выше UICollectionView?

Comment: Да, я как раз так и сделал, спасибо